# Call SOAP web services by using Apache Camel and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel. Currently I am trying to implement a use case where I need to consume a remote SOAP webservice using Spring Boot and Apache Camel.

Questions -

1. Is it possible to make call from Spring Boot and Apache Camel integration?
2. What are the required dependencies should be used in this?

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

u can .
first u need get xsd of web services and create .xsd file in resources/ws folder

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://xx.com/xx" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://xx.com/xx">
<xsd:element name="MT_INPUT_REQUEST" type="DT_INPUT_REQUEST"/>
<xsd:complexType name="DT_INPUT_REQUEST">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="EN">Key Account Order Header</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="x" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="y" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="ds" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="da" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="da" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="ddas" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="das" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="dsa" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="dasd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="da" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="dsa" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="das" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="da" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="da" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="das" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType></xsd:schema>
```

and after than u need create of this xsd 's class this plugin creates classs just run mvn clean install

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>iso8859-9</encoding>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/ws</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>*.xsd</schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

u need one marshaller for java class to byte stream u can create this way

```
public JaxbDataFormat marshaller() throws JAXBException {
    JaxbDataFormat jaxbDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance("xx.com"));
    jaxbDataFormat.setEncoding("ISO-8859-9");
    jaxbDataFormat.setFilterNonXmlChars(true);
    return jaxbDataFormat;
}
```

after that u must create a class of xsds referanced and put body after thar  unmarshall  finally call

```
.marshal(jaxbDataformat)
to("spring-ws:http://soapservice/bar")
```